# How to plot multiple graphs with ax.plot_date() in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot multiple graphs of some Excel data by using the `plot_date()` function. There is a column in the Excel file which contains dates in "2016-10-05 00:00:00" format. I am currently using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4, figsize=(12,12))
data_cols = df.columns[8:19]
for data_col, ax in zip(data_cols, axes.ravel()[:11]):
    ax.plot_date(df[data_col], df['Date'])
```

But when I use that,

[image: this kind of] graph occurs.

Also, here is  subset of my excel file
[image: excel file]

Obviously this is not what I want. How can I fix this?

Comment: Would help if you could upload your file or a subset from it

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @OykuA Worst comes to worst, you can just use `matplotlib` directly to plot whatever you want, in however many subplots you want: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html In fact, this is probably a better resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010549/subplots-with-dates-on-the-x-axis