# seaborn plot misplotting x axis dates from pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a lineplot in seaborn with values for the y axis and dates for the x axis coming from a pandas dataframe.

When I create the lineplot without converting the date column to datetime object it puts the dates in the wrong order. When I do convert the date column to datetime format it gives strange x labels and only shows 5 of the dates.

```
df = pd.read_csv("dddd.csv")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df = df.sort_values(["date"])
ax = sns.lineplot(y=df["google"],x=df["date"],color="red",data=df)

plt.show()
```

I want to just plot the data with the x labels being the dates have it in order. Here is some example data.

```
25-03-2019  -100
26-03-2019  -66.66666667
27-03-2019  -80
28-03-2019  -87.08333333
29-03-2019  -88.88888889
30-03-2019  -86.28526646
31-03-2019  -87.5
01-04-2019  -87.87878788
02-04-2019  -82.92682927
03-04-2019  -84.09090909
04-04-2019  -84.7826087
05-04-2019  -85.71428571
06-04-2019  -81.30677848
07-04-2019  -81.98051948
08-04-2019  -82.14285714
09-04-2019  -78.46153846
10-04-2019  -76.05633803
11-04-2019  -75
12-04-2019  -75
13-04-2019  -80
14-04-2019  -83.33333333
15-04-2019  -83.33333333
16-04-2019  -77.77777778
17-04-2019  -68
18-04-2019  -54.70085471
19-04-2019  -64.70588235
20-04-2019  -66.66666667
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376080/plot-numpy-datetime64-with-matplotlib), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945971/pandas-timeseries-plot-setting-x-axis-major-and-minor-ticks-and-labels), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010549/subplots-with-dates-on-the-x-axis), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465409/using-datetime-as-ticks-in-matplotlib), [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) or [this](https://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#ticks-tick-labels-and-offset-text)

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question most certainly being a duplicate, here is some explanation:

1. Without converting to `datetime`, your x-axis is unordered, because python doesn't understand the values are dates. Here it probably draws a tick for every point, because it doesn't know how to fit "16-04-2019" on a continuous scale. (Try plotting an array of strings on the x-axis as comparison).
2. If you *do* convert to `datetime`, `seaborn` and pandas are intelligent enough, to notice your dates form a continuous scale. Because the `ticklabels` would overlap when drawing all of them, it leaves out some of them and draws ticks in regular intervals instead.

You can influence the location with `ax.set_ticks(locations)`, their style with `ax.tick_params(rotation=90, horizontal_alignment='left')` or their labels with `ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`. (keywords as example).

You can also use

```py
import matplotlib.dates ad md

locs = md.YearLocator() # Locations for yearly ticks
format = md.MajorFormatter('%B %Y') # Format for labels
```

to access formatter functions and `ax.set_major_locator` / `formatter` to apply them to your plot.

To simply draw a tick for every datapoint, in your case use:

```py
ax.set_xticks(df["Date"])
```